# AWS file upload failing through API - getting 500 server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I have a website where users can upload files that I then upload onto AWS S3.

However, this service seems to be broken - the files are not getting uploaded, and I'm seeing this error message in the console:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: [http://www.rentersunion.co.uk/api/upload] the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (upload, line 0)
```

In the production logs, I see more details on this error:

```
Mar 11 13:10:04 rentersunion app/web.1: [00c0775c-2425-4789-8f20-ffb525baf510] Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId (The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.):
```

And here is the relevant `upload_controller` file:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
  class Api::V1::UploadController < ApiController
  def create
    word_detector = Pdf::WordDetectorService.new(params[:file].tempfile,params[:search_criteria], params[:chat_id])    
    Attachment.create(file: params[:file]) unless params[:file].original_filename == 'Sample.tenancy.agreement.pdf'
if word_detector.process
  render_obj word_detector.filtered
else
  render_status 422
end
end
end
```

Here is the `routes.rb` file relevant section:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
scope module: :v1 do
  resources :configurations, only: %w(index)
  resources :subscriptions, only: %w(create)
  resources :upload, only: %w(create)
  resources :log, only: %w(index create update)
  resources :sessions, only: %w(create)
```

My AWS credentials are stored in the `application.yml.sample` file and are correct.

What could be the problem?

Comment: have you renamed `application.yml.sample` to `application.yml` and restart server

Comment: Yeah, did that, no change. I looked in the logs and found the exact error - AWS ACCESS KEY not found. this doesn't make sense to me as I checked and my ACCESS KEY is valid and everything correct.

Comment: its probably worth mentioning; i used to have a different access key for this app which i deleted and have now replaced